# Only allowing selected values of different linked tables be selected. MySQL Trigger

Tags: mysql, trigger

I have 3 tables. 
I have an `instructors` table  and `facilities` table.

They are linked by `facility.facility_id=instructors.facility_id` (i.e. A facility can have many instructors but an instructor can only teach in one facility.)

The third table is `bookings`. They are linked by `instructor.instrcutor_id= bookings.instructor_id` ( An instructor can have many bookings but a booking can only have one instructor) AND `facility.facility_id=bookings.facility_id` ( A facility can have many bookings but a booking can only be for one facility)

I want a trigger that when when a `facility_id` is selected in `bookings` that only the linked `instructors` will be able to be selected. (throw up error message if needed)

This is my attempt so far----

```
DELIMITER
 //

    CREATE TRIGGER linked_instructor_to_facility
        BEFORE INSERT ON bookings
        FOR EACH ROW
            BEGIN
            SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'You can only book an instructor that is linked to that facility';
            WHERE facility.facility_id <> instructors.facility_id;
    END

//
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Please give a short example of the data and INSERT that exhibit the issue.